# adding a loop to high and low game

Tags: python, loops

```
#Welcome to my high/lower game. You will guess the second number in the game, is it higher or lower than the number presented?
# imports
import random

# declarations
num1 = (random.randint(0, 10))
num2 = (random.randint(0, 10))
guess = ""
# Now we build the program code:
print("Welcome to higher or lower, Choose whether or not the number is higher or lower")
print("The first number is", num1, "Enter h for higher or l for lower to guess the second number")
guess = input('-->')
if guess == 'h':
    if num1 < num2:
        print("you guessed it! the number is:", num2)
    else:
        print("Nice guess but the number is:", num2)
elif guess == 'l':
    if num1 > num2:
        print("you guessed it! the number is:", num2)
    else:
        print("Nice guess but the number is:", num2)
else:
    print("Not an exceptable entry")
```

I made this and it works but I want to create a loop so the user can play all they want. I am new to this ..any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After copy paste your code in my IDE I realize you miss the conception for this code.

You should start this with the idea of breaking the loop if right, continue if wrong.

This isn't a good practice but I found a quick way to answer your need without refactoring your code:

Add you entire code (except the import of random module) inside

```
while True:
```

And add `break` control statement after each good answer.

I tested it and it's work but I recommend you to search for similar project to compare with your, it will be a good point for later in your adventure.

Comment: thank you so much! so I need to just remove the random module completely?

Comment: No I just meant that you have to loop the entire code except the import of random module which should remains at the top of your script

Answer (score 0):

Using functions here would be a good idea, I'd recommend putting your main code in a function called 'play' for example and also create a function which prompts the user if he wants to play again.

Then create a while loop which calls your 'play' function, and update the condition of your main loop after each 'play' with the prompt function.

This is how I have done it.

```
# Welcome to my high/lower game. You will guess the second number in the game, is it higher or lower than the number presented?
# imports
import random

# Now we build the program code:
print("Welcome to higher or lower, Choose whether or not the number is higher or lower")


def play():
    # declarations
    num1 = (random.randint(0, 10))
    num2 = (random.randint(0, 10))
    print("The first number is", num1, "Enter h for higher or l for lower to guess the second number")
    guess = input('-->')
    if guess == 'h':
        if num1 < num2:
            print("you guessed it! the number is:", num2)
        else:
            print("Nice guess but the number is:", num2)
    elif guess == 'l':
        if num1 > num2:
            print("you guessed it! the number is:", num2)
        else:
            print("Nice guess but the number is:", num2)
    else:
        print("Not an exceptable entry")


def promptAgain():
    print("Play again? y/n")
    response = input().lower()
    if response == 'n':
        return False
    elif response == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        print("Not an exceptable entry")
        return promptAgain()


again = True
while again:
    play()
    again = promptAgain()
```

Comment: Notice in the promptAgain function I return promptAgain() when the user enters an incorrect input. This will ask the user for the correct input again. Might be good to apply something like that to the play function aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only allow higher or lower input you need to ensure the same number is not randomly selected twice. I.e., if `num1` is `8` then `num2` should not be able to also be `8` (your current code doesn't prevent this).

Consider utilizing [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to achieve this:

```
"""Daniel Gardner's Higher/Lower Game."""
import random

MIN_RAND_VALUE = 0
MAX_RAND_VALUE = 10
GUESS_PROMPT = '--> '
HIGH_GUESS = 'h'
LOW_GUESS = 'l'


def get_yes_no_input(prompt: str) -> bool:
    """Returns True if the user enters yes."""
    allowed_responses = {'y', 'yes', 'n', 'no'}
    user_input = input(prompt).lower()
    while user_input not in allowed_responses:
        user_input = input(prompt).lower()
    return user_input[0] == 'y'


def higher_or_lower_game_loop() -> None:
    num1, num2 = random.sample(range(MIN_RAND_VALUE, MAX_RAND_VALUE + 1), 2)
    print('The first number is', num1,
          'Enter h for higher or l for lower to guess the second number.')
    guess = input(GUESS_PROMPT)
    while guess not in {HIGH_GUESS, LOW_GUESS}:
        print('Not an exceptable entry, you must enter h or l')
        guess = input(GUESS_PROMPT)
    if guess == HIGH_GUESS:
        if num1 < num2:
            print('You guessed it! the number is:', num2)
        else:
            print('Nice guess but the number is:', num2)
    elif guess == LOW_GUESS:
        if num1 > num2:
            print('You guessed it! the number is:', num2)
        else:
            print('Nice guess but the number is:', num2)


def main() -> None:
    print('Welcome to my high/lower game.',
          'You will guess the second number in the game,',
          'is it higher or lower than the number presented?')
    while True:
        higher_or_lower_game_loop()
        play_again = get_yes_no_input('Play again? ')
        if not play_again:
            break
    print('Goodbye!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Welcome to my high/lower game. You will guess the second number in the game, is it higher or lower than the number presented?
The first number is 8 Enter h for higher or l for lower to guess the second number.
--> l
You guessed it! the number is: 5
Play again? yes
The first number is 10 Enter h for higher or l for lower to guess the second number.
--> l
You guessed it! the number is: 8
Play again? n
Goodbye!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize recursion and while loop to validate input:

```
from random import sample

def hilow():
    num1, num2 = sample(range(1, 11), 2); # print(num1, num2)
    print(f"The first number is {num1} Enter h for higher or l for lower to guess the second number")
    while (guess:=input('-->').lower()) not in ('h','l'):print("Not an exceptable entry")
    res = guess == 'h' and num1 < num2 or guess == 'l' and num1 > num2
    print((f"Nice guess but the number is {num2}",f"you guessed it! the number is {num2}")[res])
    while (p:=input("Play again (y/n)?: ").lower()) not in ('y','n'):print("Not an exceptable entry")
    p == 'n' or hilow()

print("Welcome to higher or lower, Choose whether or not the number is higher or lower")
hilow()
```

Output:

```
Welcome to higher or lower, Choose whether or not the number is higher or lower
The first number is 2 Enter h for higher or l for lower to guess the second number
-->h
you guessed it! the number is 7
Play again (y/n)?: z
Not an exceptable entry
Play again (y/n)?: y
The first number is 2 Enter h for higher or l for lower to guess the second number
-->l
Nice guess but the number is 5
Play again (y/n)?: y
The first number is 3 Enter h for higher or l for lower to guess the second number
-->x
Not an exceptable entry
-->h
you guessed it! the number is 6
Play again (y/n)?: n
```